# Convert simple for loop to a while loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am new to python and I am trying to convert this simple for loop to a while loop. I'm not sure why I am not getting the same output. Many thanks.

```
for var in (1,2,3,4,5):
   total=total+var
   print(total)

#my attempt
var=0.0
while(var<6):
   var=var+1
   print(var)
```

Comment: Why is `var` set to 0? Why the condition is set to `< 7` compared to your for loop ending with 5 ?

Comment: Change to `for var in (1,2,3,4,5,6):` or `while(var<6):` (not both :))

Comment: Your for loop goes through the values in the Tuple you provided `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. You increase total with those items. Meaning total will print `1`, `3`, `6`, `10`, `15`.  Your while loop is a simple counter that is increased by 1 every time.

Comment: Why do you expect the same output? In one case you are adding 1,2,3,4,5, while in the other you add 1  6 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just convert my comment to an answer with different ways on how to fix it.
for-loop:

```
for var in (1,2,3,4,5):
   total=total+var
   print(total)
```

Assuming `total = 0` before the loop, in each cycle of the for loop `var` takes the next item in the Tuple you provided. Because you add those values to `total` you get the same functionality as the function `sum` which pretty much summarizes values in a collection.

while-loop:

```
var=0.0
while(var<6):
   var=var+1
   print(var)
```

Here what you are doing is count repetition, as opposed to the summarizing functionality in the for-loop.
For every cycle you increase `var` value by 1.

Your options:

1. Summarizing

```
total = 0
for var in (1,2,3,4,5):
   total= total + var
   print(total)

total = 0
var = 0
while var < 5:
   var += 1
   total += var
   print(total)
```

2. Repetition counting:

```
for var in (1,2,3,4,5):
   print(var)

var = 0.0
while var < 5:
   var += 1
   print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason You are not getting the same answer because, while using while you are just incrementing the loop by 1.
The below code will help you

```
var=0
count=0
while(var<6):
    count=count+var
    var=var+1
print(count)
```

Comment: Isn't that the same answer as @Prerak Mathur but using a different variable name?

Answer (score 0):

'Unrolling' both loops makes the answer obvious. E.g.

```
total=0
for var in (1,2,3):
   total=total+var
   print(total)
```

is the same thing as:

```
total = 0
var = 1
total = total + var
print(total)

var = 2
total = total + var
print(total)

var = 3
total = total + var
print(total)
```

It is clear now that `total` is a arithmetic series (0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n).

Doing the same to the `while` loop:

```
var=0.0
while(var<3):
   var=var+1
   print(var)
```

is the same thing as:

```
var = 0.0

var = var + 1
print(var)

var = var + 1
print(var)

var = var + 1
print(var)
```

From which it is obvious that the `while` loop is simply incrementing `var` by `1` on each iteration.

Note I have decreased the iterations in each loop for brevity, but the same logic equally applies to longer loops.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your while loop code is that, you have only defined counter (which is var = 0.0) at the start of while loop, you should also declare a variable for total sum of all elements

```
total=0
var=1
while(var<6):
   total=total+var
   print(total)
   var=var+1
```

This will work

Answer (score -1):

The problem is a logic error in your code. In the for loop, you go over a tuple and add the resulting value. In the while loop, you are incrementing based on counter.

This is how you do it.

```
list_items = [1,2,3,4,5]
total = 0

while list_items:
  item = list_items.pop()
  total += item
  print(item)
```